# How does position uncertainty change in time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I have an online homework for my Modern Physics class, that requires me to find the uncertainty in velocity and position of a duck. The question is as below:

> Suppose a duck lives in a universe in which h = 2π J · s. The duck has
>   a mass of 2.55 kg and is initially known to be within a pond 1.70 m
>   wide.    (a) What is the minimum uncertainty in the component of the
>   duck's velocity parallel to the pond's width?     (b) Assuming this
>   uncertainty in speed prevails for 4.10 s, determine the uncertainty in
>   the duck's position after this time interval.

Now, I got the solution to the first part using the equation

$$
\Delta(x).\Delta(p) = h / 4\pi
$$

This gives me $$ \Delta(v) > 0.1153$$

I assume, the second part of the question would be calculated this way:

$$\Delta(x) = \Delta(v) . t$$
or, $$ \Delta(x) = 0.1153 * 4.10$$

But this shows up as the wrong answer. What am I doing wrong? Wouldn't the uncertainty in the duck's position after time t equal the product of velocity uncertainty and time?

*(Disclaimer: Yes, this is a homework question as I mentioned above, but I have tried to solve it and seem to be hitting a wall. I suppose I have some concept wrong. A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.)*

Comment: Is the duck confined to the pond, or can it get out and start walking over land? (And I suppose we should ask, does its wavefunction continue to evolve in the same way over land as it does over water? But I have a hunch that's more detail than you are meant to think about for this... one of the reasons I'm starting to think I don't like this problem.) On another note, here's a hint: if $\Delta x = \Delta v t$, what would be the uncertainty at $t=0$? Does that agree with what you know to be the uncertainty at $t=0$?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Thanks for the hint. That helped me find the solution. I was doing $$\Delta(x) = \Delta(v)t$$, but as you said, that does not agree with our initial information. I got the answer by doing $$ \Delta(x) = \Delta(v)t. \Delta(x_{initial})$$

Comment: OK, good. If you were able to find the solution, could you write it up and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following David Zaslavsky hint (see comments under question), I realized what I was doing wrong.

I was solving using

$$
\Delta(x) = \Delta(v).t
$$

This would give me
$$\Delta(x) = 0.47273$$

However, I wasn't taking into consideration the initial uncertainty in position.

Thus the correct was of doing it was,

$$\Delta(x) = \Delta(v).t + \Delta(x_{initial})$$
$$ \Delta(x) = 0.47273 + 1.70 = 2.17273$$

Comment: Although you did the problem right, this problem is terrible is many ways.